# The cruelty with visitors in Sodom and Gomorrah

Tags: midrash, sodom-ammorah

They say that there was a special type of cruelty in Sodom and Gomorrah. If they received a visitor in the city who needed shelter, they would take him to a room with a bed. If the visitor was a tall man, they would cut him until he would fit in the bed, and if he was a small man they would stretch him until he would also fit in the bed. Does anyone know the source for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.109b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in sanhadrin 109b says the following:

הויא להו פורייתא דהוו מגני עלה אורחין כי מאריך גייזי ליה כי גוץ מתחין ליה אליעזר עבד אברהם אקלע להתם אמרו ליה קום גני אפוריא אמר להון נדרא נדרי מן יומא דמיתת אמא לא גנינא אפוריא

The Gemara continues to discuss the sins of the people of Sodom: They had beds on which they would lay their guests; when a guest was longer than the bed they would cut him, and when a guest was shorter than the bed they would stretch him. Eliezer, servant of Abraham, happened to come there. They said to him: Come lie on the bed. He said to them: I took a vow that since the day my mother died I do not lie on a bed.

Comment: Famous quote from R' Yaakov Kaminetsky ... some schools seem to operate this way; if the child doesn't fit the school's model ...